# Android MalformedJsonException when deserializing from .NET serialized String

Tags: android, gson

I'm trying to parse this `serialized String` using `Gson`.

```
{
//other variables
"MODIFIED_ON":"/Date(1490354840000)/",
"MARKET_APP_URL":"http://marketplac...",
//other variables
}
```

I posted only those two lines because those are the ones throwing errors.

This `String` is coming from a `C# webservice`, which is using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject)`.

This is my error:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected value at line 1 column 1 path $

My problems are in this line and in the other one since it's containing some characters like `+`, `\`. `(`, `)`, ...

I tried replacing the date for an easier format but I can't even use `Split` with those Strings..

How can I deserialize this `String` without going on problems like this one?

This is my code with a custom `Serializer` for datas:

```
JsonDeserializer<Date> deser = new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {       
  @Override
  public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
    JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
      String s = json.getAsString();
      if (s.contains("Date")) {
        s = s.split(String.valueOf('('))[1].split(String.valueOf(')'))[0];
        return new Date(Long.parseLong(s));
      } 
      else 
        return new Date(Long.valueOf("-2208988800000"));
  }
};
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, deser).create();
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement mJson = parser.parse(Pattern.quote(userInfo));
LoggedUser loggedUser = gson.fromJson(mJson, LoggedUser.class); //this line is throwing the error
```

Comment: i think you will crash in `s.split(String.valueOf('('))[1]` because you have one `(` and index one must be crash with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. ( array index is zero base )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

First, `Pattern.quote` is designed to quote *regular expressions*. Whatever you're going to do with it will wrap a quoted string wrapped in `\Q` and `\E` at the head and the tail respectively:

```java
System.out.println(Pattern.quote("foo"));
```

Turns into:

```
\Qfoo\E
```

to delimit the quoted regular expression. This causes the JSON parser to fail: your JSON document becomes unparsable because of those regex literals. Just don't use it there:

> Expected value at line 1 column 1 path $

Next, you don't need to create `JsonParser`. It's purpose is creating in-memory JSON trees from the given input. Thus, besides the given input, you'll get an intermediate JSON tree (`JsonElement` and its subclasses) that consumes memory and some performance with no reason.

Third, using regular expressions to extract text is not that bad. I'm not sure about the real performance comparing to string slicing with substrings, but at least it will give your some more expression:

```java
final class DateJsonDeserializer
        implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    // Can be a singleton, but exposing via a factory method and leaving the constructor private (let the caller not care on _how_ this is instantiated)
    private static final JsonDeserializer<Date> dateJsonDeserializer = new DateJsonDeserializer();

    // /\/Date\(\d+\)\// as if it were sed
    private static final Pattern datePattern = Pattern.compile("/Date\\((\\d+)\\)/");
    // Just cache your default date, note the L literal for longs, so no need to parseLong at all

    private DateJsonDeserializer() {
    }

    static JsonDeserializer<Date> getDateJsonDeserializer() {
        return dateJsonDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        final String dateLiteral = jsonElement.getAsString();
        final Matcher matcher = datePattern.matcher(dateLiteral);
        // Not a valid date literal? Better throw an exception or improve the parser somehow, but don't return 1900 if possible
        if ( !matcher.matches() ) {
            throw new JsonParseException("Cannot parse: " + dateLiteral);
        }
        return new Date(parseLong(matcher.group(1)));
    }

}
```

Sample mapping:

```java
final class LoggedUser {

    @SerializedName("MODIFIED_ON")
    final Date modifiedOn = null;

    @SerializedName("MARKET_APP_URL")
    final URL marketAppUrl = null;

}
```

```java
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, getDateJsonDeserializer())
        .create();
final LoggedUser loggedUser = gson.fromJson(JSON, LoggedUser.class);
System.out.println(loggedUser.modifiedOn);
System.out.println(loggedUser.marketAppUrl);
```

Output:

> Fri Mar 24 13:27:20 EET 2017
>   http://marketplac...

Comment: You gave me so many informations about things I didn't know on Gson, Pettern, Matcher, Singleton and code styling that I don't think an upvote and an accept might be enough for thanking you! but since it's all I can do, thanks a lot!

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley No problem, I'm glad I could help you out!

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley Sorry, I made a mistake in my initial answer, and please check out the edit: the `defaultDate` must not be cached, because `java.util.Date` is mutable, and if someone gets the default date and then modifies it, all subsequent gettings for the default date will be reflected by this modification.